# Property "TbMenu.itemCssClass" is not defined

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

I'm getting this error with the latest version of the [bootstrap extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap/) when using the TbMenu widget

```
Property "TbMenu.itemCssClass" is not defined


if ($this->itemCssClass !== null)
  $classes[] = $this->itemCssClass;
```

Also, I don't get the error on my local machine, only on a live server. Does anyone have any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**itemCssClass** property is inherited from **zii.widgets.CMenu** class which was added since YII **v1.1.9**, so for older version of YII it is not available.
As quick fix for this issue you can change line 66 in {extensions}/bootstrap/widgets/TbBaseMenu.php file to:

```
if (isset($this->itemCssClass) && $this->itemCssClass !== null)
```

but it is highly recommended to upgrade your YII installation to the latest stable version.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check you're installation of yii-bootstrap. That property should definitely exist on that class.

Try viewing that file on the live server and it should be (in mine at least) line 36 in `{extensions}/bootstrap/widgets/TBMenu`

If it's not you might want to debug a little further into why you're development machine is out of sync with Live.